# SQL Server, check constraint on nullability of multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server there are columns `column a` and `column b`. Only if value for `column a` is present, `column b` should be not null. Can you do it before inserting values that is in create scripts and how can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

Using such CHECK constraint:

```
USE tempdb;
CREATE TABLE test
(
    col1 INT,
    col2 INT
);

ALTER TABLE test
ADD CONSTRAINT ck_combined CHECK 
(
    (
        col1 IS NOT NULL
        AND col2 IS NOT NULL
    )
    OR (col1 IS NULL)
);

-- (1 row affected)
INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL, NULL);

--Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 10
--The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "ck_combined". The conflict occurred in database "tempdb", table "dbo.test".
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, NULL);
```

Comment: @lee, nice that the question was addressed. Since this is a Q&A site, can you then please mark it as answered?

Answer (score 0):

Yes  it is possible using **check constraints**

try this  -

```
create table myTable (ID int identity(1,1)
                        , a int
                        , b int 
                        )
go

ALTER TABLE myTable 
ADD CONSTRAINT ck_BNotNull 
CHECK ( 
        (A is not null and b is not null) 
        or  (A is null)

        )

   go
```

**-- Not allowed**

```
  insert into myTable
   (a,b)
   values
   (1,null)
```

**-- allowed**

```
insert into myTable
   (a,b)
   values
   (null,null)
```

**-- allowed**

```
 insert into myTable
   (a,b)
   values
   (null,1)
```